# How can I use the let variable on scope outside the socket event, in the Node.JS code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers

How can I use the let variable 'equipe' on scope outside the socket event, in the Node.JS code?

```
socket.on('equipConnected', (data) => {
       let equip = equips.Equip.deserializeBinary(data);
       console.log(equip.getName());        
    });
```

Comment: You shouldn't really because you would have no idea when it's valid and multiple users hitting your server will cause it's value to change without warning.  So, you really ought to change your question to what you're really trying to do so we can better help you solve the real problem because what you asked for is NOT the way to solve it.

Comment: OK, but how I emit this informations for a socket client? Whereas the question event happens on server.js

Comment: I don't understand what that last comment means.  You tagged your question as node.js so I assume you're showing us server-side code.

Comment: Yes! It's the server code! My question now is how do I send using emit the data from the 'equip' variable to a client via socket.io?

Comment: To send to a client, you use `socket.emit()`.  Still not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'll send the client and server code ...

Comment: server: https://gist.github.com/evertfreit77/5c5077e3f9e98a7aa99458242a00ec91
client: https://gist.github.com/evertfreit77/2bfb7636cac774bfb745610f78a0d545

Comment: But is not showing log in the client terminal...

Comment: Your client code sends `clientConnected` to the server, but the server doesn't do anything with that, other than one log message.  No further messages are sent.

Comment: I solve the problem by sending the emit no event on clientConnected?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (by [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)):

```
let equip;

socket.on('equipConnected', (data) => {
    equip = equips.Equip.deserializeBinary(data);
    console.log(equip.getName());        
});

// somewhere in your code:
function doSth() {
  console.log(equip);
}
```

better (by parameter):

```
socket.on('equipConnected', (data) => {
    doSth(equips.Equip.deserializeBinary(data));
    console.log(equip.getName());        
});

function doSth(equip) {
  console.log(equip);
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely the first option is a valid or desirable way to solve a problem in a multi-user server.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't teach a newbie something that only works properly in a debug situation and not in a real server situation.  That's the point of my comment.  It is not a recommended way to solve a server-side problem and thus should not be present in a good answer.